# Css - Last Table Row Regardless of TD or TH

Tags: html, css

How can I use a CSS selector that will always catch the last row of a table and apply a rule to the last division, regardless if it is a TD or a TH, but not altering the last TH in the table.

My current rule only applies to if it is a TD, and all ways that I've found to make the TH round, it would round even if there's more TDs in it.

```
.tabGeral tr:first-child th:first-child  {
    border-top-left-radius:14px;
}
.tabGeral tr:first-child th:last-child  {
    border-top-right-radius:14px;
}
.tabGeral tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius:14px;
}
.tabGeral tr:last-child td:first-child{
    border-bottom-left-radius:14px;
}
```

Top two are the desired result, the two on the bottom is what I'm achieving
[image: Top two are the desired result, the two below is what I'm achieving]

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rd48cfw8/3/

The two dark green are THs, the light colored green is a TD, I need them to be TH and TD because of table sorter.

If I use only `tr:last-child td:first-child`, the second table isn't achieved, if I use only `tr:last-child th:first-child`, the first table isn't achieved, if I use a combination of both, I get the fourth table, not desired.

Comment: If you provide us a Fiddle/CodePen/code snippet with HTML and CSS it would be easier to help you.

Comment: @DineiA.Rockenbach https://jsfiddle.net/rd48cfw8/

Comment: OT: You are using table elements incorrectly. It looks like `<th>`'s are being used for styling, which they serve a different purpose for.

Comment: please tick the answer if it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

to get the second last table row you would use

```
tr:nth-last-child(2) {}
```

You could then style the `td` with

This selects from the rear first so

```
tr:nth-last-child(1) {}
```

Would be the very last child and so on.

You can style the `td` in the second last `tr` as such

```
tr:nth-last-child(2) td {
   (whatever styling you want.)
}
```

UPDATE:

Here is a fiddle I fixed it with:

```
.tabGeral:last-child tr:last-child th {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 9px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rd48cfw8/4/)

Comment: Updated with your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use overflow hidden on your table so that it cuts off the border-radius